# How to sort 'react-data-table-component' by column number

Tags: reactjs

I am using '**react-data-table-component**' in React JS.

Following is my sample structure:

`import DataTable from "react-data-table-component";`

```
const data = myData;
const columns = [
   {
      name: 'Date',
      selector: 'dateOfAction',
      cell: row => <div>{moment(row.dateOfAction).format("MM-DD-YYYY A")}</div>,
      sortable: true,
   },
   {
      name: 'History Date',
      selector: 'dateOfAction',   
      cell: row => <div>{moment(row.dateOfAction).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")}</div>,
      sortable: true,
   } 
];

<DataTable
   columns={columns}
   data={data}
   defaultSortField="dateOfAction"
   pagination
   striped
   defaultSortAsc={false}
 />
```

Here, Both columns have **same selector**.

And, I am able to sort data by first column i.e **'Date'** but I want to sort table data by last column i.e **'History Date'**.

How should I sort data by last column?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can pass the defaultSortFieldId prop in the DataTable component. According to the documentation:

> The defaultSortFieldId sets the a column to be pre sorted and
> corresponds to the a column definition id

This means that you will need to provide an unique id for each column and then pass the id you want to use to the defaultSortFieldId:

```
const columns = [
       {
          id: 'date',
          name: 'Date',
          selector: 'dateOfAction',
          cell: row => <div>{moment(row.dateOfAction).format("MM-DD-YYYY A")}</div>,
          sortable: true,
       },
       {
          id: 'historyDate',
          name: 'History Date',
          selector: 'dateOfAction',   
          cell: row => <div>{moment(row.dateOfAction).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")}</div>,
          sortable: true,
       } 
    ];

<DataTable
   columns={columns}
   data={data}
   defaultSortFieldId="historyDate"
   pagination
   striped
   defaultSortAsc={false}
 />
```